if template class<T> T=int&, why method set(const T val) !== set(const int& val)? const ignored why
If T=int&, why .set(const T val) !== .set(const int& val)?
template <class T>
struct ClassA{
public:
    T data;                   // T == int&;
public:
    void set(const T val){    // T == int&;  why !== set(const int& val)
       this->data = val;
    }
};

void main(){
    int num = 1;
    ClassA<int&> instance {num};
    const int val = 100;
    instance.set(val);  // gcc error: binding reference of type 'int&' to 'const int' discards qualifiers
}

I don't know what the rules on this site are; https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language

this->data is not const, hence why it fails.

In other words, gcc is not telling that set() removed the ref, gcc tells you that you have val which is a const int, then you take it as a const int & (set(const int &)) and then you assign it to data which is an int &. In the end, you are trying to bind data to val (i.e. bind an int & to a const int, which is not allowed)

In any case this.data should be this->data.

The instantiated function is actually void set(int & val) because const is ignored because you're trying to apply const on a reference which is not allowed/possible. See Cannot apply const to typedef reference

In any case void main should be int main.

@wohlstad -- and this->data should be data. 

@PeteBecker sure, but if the OP insist on explicit this, they should at least be aware how to dereference it ...


[dcl.ref] ... Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the
cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef-name
([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or decltype-specifier
([dcl.type.simple]), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored

When T is a reference, like your int &, const T is also int &.  The const is ignored.
You may have a reference to something that is const or volatile, but the reference itself cannot be const or volatile.
